# /scripts/installimagemagick is now deprecated

Tags: subversion, imagemagick, cpanel, redmine

I am trying to install Redmine With SVN following [this](https://www.howtoforge.com/installation-of-redmine-with-svn-on-a-cpanel-centos-5.6-server) article.

But when i run `/scripts/checkimagemagick` this command

```
-bash: /scripts/checkimagemagick: No such file or directory
```

and when i run `/scripts/installimagemagick`

```
info [installimagemagick] scripts/installimagemagick is now deprecated. The ImageMagick from your distro will now be installed.
```

`convert --version` is working fine. it show

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.5.4-7 2014-02-10 Q16 OpenMP http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2009 ImageMagick Studio LLC
```

I am trying to install it on Centos 6.4 x64 VPS server where WHM is installed.

I can't install Redmine due to this error.

Answer (score 0):

You have installed the latest version of ImageMagick available through cPanel at this time. It is an info message and is saying that the cPanel is not compiling from the source to install the ImageMagick and instead using the rpm (yum). You can proceed with the next steps as ImageMagick is installed as you showed from the

> convert --version
>   Version: ImageMagick 6.5.4-7 2014-02-10 Q16 OpenMP http://www.imagemagick.org
>   Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2009 ImageMagick Studio LLC

Comment: I have finished 1st page and now i am stuck [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/installation-of-redmine-with-svn-on-a-cpanel-centos-5.6-server-p2) i can't install the bundle

Comment: Issue you reported is different then and you would need to show the error you got while installing the bundle.